# creating a table for four times only

Tags: java

I have put this code bu can't get the desired results.

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i+=2/* FINISH ME */) {
        for (int j =1; j < 5; j++){

        System.out.println("2 times " + j + " = " + (i*j));
        }
    }
```

And output was,

```
2 times 1 = 2
2 times 2 = 4
2 times 3 = 6
2 times 4 = 8
2 times 1 = 4
2 times 2 = 8
2 times 3 = 12
2 times 4 = 16
```

I don;t understand why the loop ran for 8 times and how the calculation gone so after four times?

Comment: @JackFlamp no, because that wouldn't increase the value of i

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i < 4; i+=2) {`

Comment: @SunnyKk your outer loop runs 2 times. Your inner loop runs 4 times for each iteration of the outer loop. 2*4 = 8

Comment: your 2nd for loop runs 2 times because the first loop isnt finished yet

Comment: @Stultuske dude you are right. embarassing, hehe.. nevermind

Comment: Try printing out `i` as well - that should explain what's going on in your code to a decent extent. Although it's not really clear **why** you expect it to run only 4 times (telling us that would make it easier for us to point out where you're going wrong).

Comment: @JackFlamp happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @Stultuske yes, well not Jon Skeet of course.. but us normal humans yes :)

Comment: without exception, no rule :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is going on in your loops:
At the very beginning of your first loop **i** is set to 2, and then inner loop is starting and you get:

```
2 times 1 = 2 
2 times 2 = 4
2 times 3 = 6
2 times 4 = 8
```

Then first iteration comes to an end, so 2 is added to **i** (i+=2) and then it checks if **i<=4** and since i==4 now in fact it is less **or equal 4**, so second iteration starts:

```
2 times 1 = 4 // i==4, so it is 4 times 1!!
2 times 2 = 8 //i==4, so it is 4 times 2!!
2 times 3 = 12
2 times 4 = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, figuring out how many times a nested for loop will be run is just multiplication. You multiply the number of times the outer loop runs by the number of times the inner loop runs.

Here:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i+=2) {
    for (int j =1; j < 5; j++){

    System.out.println("2 times " + j + " = " + (i*j));
    }
}
```

The first loop runs for 2 times. The first time `i` is 2, the second time `i` is 4. There is no third time because `i` will then be `6` which is not less than or equal to 4.

The second loop is easier to figure out. You count up from 1 until it is not less than 5 anymore, so 1, 2, 3, 4, **4** times!

Now we can multiply 4 and 2 together to get 8, which is exactly how many times your `System.out.println` line is called.

Now, let's figure out the values of `i` and `j`. In a nested for loop, the variable in the inner loop changes at a faster rate than the one in the outer loop. It is only after the inner loop finishes, does the outer loop's variable change. So `i` starts off with 2, then `j` goes 1, 2, 3, 4 and the inner loop finishes. Now `i` is 4 and `j` goes 1, 2, 3, 4 again.

Now let's address the question of why the output says blatantly wrong things like `2 times 4 = 16`. This is because of your print statement. You've made it so that it always starts with `2 times` then `j`, then the value of `i * j`. So while `i` changes to 4 in the second iteration of the outer loop, you are still printing `2 times`, when it should have been `4 times`. To fix this, simply do:

```
System.out.println(i + " times " + j + " = " + (i*j));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little modification to your code. Hopefully, this will help you to understand your problem.

```
    int loopCount = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println("loopCount = " + ++loopCount + " : i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
loopCount = 1 : i = 2, j = 1
loopCount = 2 : i = 2, j = 2
loopCount = 3 : i = 2, j = 3
loopCount = 4 : i = 2, j = 4

loopCount = 5 : i = 4, j = 1
loopCount = 6 : i = 4, j = 2
loopCount = 7 : i = 4, j = 3
loopCount = 8 : i = 4, j = 4
```